# jQuery show/hide within Twitter Bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-selectors, twitter-bootstrap

Here's some code that works on a normal page but won't function within a bootstrap modal, any idea why this might not work?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.box').hide();
  $('#dropdown').change(function() {
    $('.box').hide();
    $('#div' + $(this).val()).show();
 });
});
</script>
<form>
 <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
  <option value="0">Choose</option>
  <option value="area1">DIV Area 1</option>
  <option value="area2">DIV Area 2</option>
  <option value="area3">DIV Area 3</option>
 </select>
</form>
<div id="divarea1" class="box">DIV Area 1</div>
<div id="divarea2" class="box">DIV Area 2</div>
<div id="divarea3" class="box">DIV Area 3</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `$(document).ready()` would have already been fired when the parent page is loaded.  You should listen for bootstrap modal's `shown` event.  I'm assuming you're AJAX'ing in the modal content?

Comment: Cool. What's the proper way to listen for the shown event? Right now the content is coming in through the django template.

Comment: Use jQuery `.on` to attach the listener to a common parent (like `document`) and then it doesn't matter where things are done so long as they are within the same `window` object (and it doesn't matter what's behind it on the server).  Something like `$(document).on('shown', function(event) {/*existing callback*/});`.  I'd recommend also using a selector for clarity and guarding, but it's not essential.